# SharePoint 2013 - How search and replace html for all pages from a Pages Library location

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

If I was ever in a situation where I had to move 1000 PDF documents from one document library  to another, what is the best way to then update all 1000 of my SharePoint pages (from my Pages library), that was referencing /SiteCollectionDocuments/ in HTML anchor links?

I am a UI front-end developer,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One Solution:

In your master page write a script to check if the current anchor list is triggered, if yes change the location.
As shown below

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('a').click(function(event) {


                if($(this).attr('href').indexOf('SiteCollectionDocuments') > -1);
                {
                event.preventDefault();
                var oldNav=$(this).attr('href');
                var newNav=oldNav.replace("SiteCollectionDocuments", "NewSiteCollectionDocuments");
                window.location=newNav;
                //i want to prevent
            } 
        });
    });
    </script>

    <body>
    <a href="http://www.SiteCollectionDocuments.com" id="yes">Read More &gt;&gt;</a>
    </body>
```

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your query

Comment: Thank you Varun.  I may have other PDF's in that original SiteCollectionDocuments, that will not be moved...